# litteral search with encrypted data with MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, encryption

I use these functions to encrypt / decrypt my data in MySQL Database:

```
'use strict';

const crypto = require('crypto');

const ENCRYPTION_KEY = process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY; // Must be 256 bytes (32 characters)
const IV_LENGTH = 16; // For AES, this is always 16

function encrypt(text) {
  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', new Buffer(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text);

  encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

  return iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted.toString('hex');
}

function decrypt(text) {
  let textParts = text.split(':');
  let iv = new Buffer(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
  let encryptedText = new Buffer(textParts.join(':'), 'hex');
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', new Buffer(ENCRYPTION_KEY), iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);

  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);

  return decrypted.toString();
}

module.exports = { decrypt, encrypt };
```

(from this [link](https://gist.github.com/vlucas/2bd40f62d20c1d49237a109d491974eb))

Now, I'd like to do a litteral search from my database. What is the best way to do it?

For example, I store encrypted names  in my database but i'd like to be able to search lines with specific names.

Comment: I don't see it as a feasible option as you would have to decrypt each string before doing the comparison (note that every encryption is unique as you are using a random iv, so encrypting the search string once would not work; furthermore as encryption is handled at binary level encoding issue can arise too). If your concern is security you should care about restricting access to database, not make data unreadable.

Comment: I've seen this in php: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql so I thinkj this is possible, no ?

Comment: yes it is, but you have to maintain extra fields

Comment: I do not really understand the chapter called  "Implementing Fuzzier Searching for Encrypted Data". and what I have to do in my database and in my function during encryption and during decryption...any help?

Comment: It is tough to do this, but a better design would be to use elastic search (ES), index your data without storing actual data and only store the database reference id. Then search ES to get the record id and fetch the same from your DB.

Comment: I suspect that encrypting each row differently does not increase the security of the data.  Rethink that.

Comment: I do not see the point with my question but I'm very interested with your point of view. Why do you say that?